# Huawei E682 modem not working in 12.04

Tags: networking, modem, usb-modem, huawei

I'm a user of Ubuntu in Kenya, I've a Huawei E682 modem. When I use it in Ubuntu 11.04 it connects without any problems to the Internet. But in Ubuntu 12.04 I can hardly connect to the Internet using it. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Kiswahili language, for my Kenyan friend "Niaje, ata me niko Kenya, kumbe hii shida si yangu pekee."

Ok, about the querry,

I'm experiencing the same problem, I've been searching for the solution for a while now. I've gathered information from the net and I think I might have a potential solution (though I have not tried it yet)

First, **download** the Huawei **Linux Driver Tool** from [here](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=NDcwMzU=). The **guide** to installing the Driver tool can be downloaded from [here](http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/Support/Downloads/) (it is the last one on the list, in PDF form). When installation is successful, your Huawei 3G modem should work just fine.

If it still does not work, it is probably because the Huawei Driver Tool modified the USB-modeswitch Data Files. To re-install these data files, run the following commands in the terminal (Ctril+Alt+T):

```
sudo apt-get remove usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch
```